# How can I check at compile time that an ID is only used on the object instance that generated it?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Let's say that I have a class that manages "identifiers" that can be later used to look up data.  For instance, if I wanted to manage some objects of class `Foo`, I could have:

```
Manager<Foo> manager;
Id<Foo> id = manager.create();
```

In this example, `Id` is just a generic identifier like a `struct` with some generic meta information that does not depend on the template parameter at all. The only thing the template parameter does is add some type safety by using a [phantom type](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/243154/c-strongly-typed-typedef).  The phantom type would prevent me from ever accidentally passing an `Id<Foo>` to a manager object of type `Manager<Bar>`, even though the underlying type of the `Id` is exactly the same struct.  In contrast to a plain old `int`, the phantom type makes certain at compile time that I don't use `Id` with a `Manager` of the wrong type.

Now, I want to take this idea a step further.  Instead of enforcing that `Manager<Foo>` only accepts identifiers of type `Id<Foo>`, I want to enforce that the specific instance of `Manager<Foo>` only accepts identifiers created by itself in the call to `create()`.  This would prevent an object of class `Manager<T>` from accepting an identifier of `Id<T>` that was created by a different instance of `Manager<T>`.  Since an identifier is only valid in the context of the manager that created it, this would detect at compile time that an ID is passed to the wrong manager instance even if the type being managed happens to be the same.

Specifically, I would like usage akin to the below sample code to throw a compiler error.  It doesn't have to be exactly like this, but I don't want to require too much hoop jumping by the class user (myself).

```
Manager<Foo> m1;
Manager<Foo> m2;
Id<Foo> id1 = m1.create();
Id<Foo> id2 = m2.create();
Foo myFoo = m2.lookup(id1); // <-- causes compiler error. id1 used on m2.
```

I would prefer something that works in C++11 or earlier, but C++14 is acceptable, too.

Comment: To do this at compile time you'd need to add something to the types so that they were all distinct.  You could check for this at runtime by tracking the IDs created in each Manager, and verifying that when you use the Id.

Comment: Is something like `Manager<Foo, 42>` and `Id<Foo, 42>` acceptable ?

Comment: It's a noble goal but completely impossible if you cannot use separate types. Consider `Id<Foo>& id = GetRandomNumber() ? id1 : id2; Foo myFoo = m2.lookup(id);`. The compiler cannot predict the future.

Comment: Instances don't exist until runtime, therefore they cannot be identified at compile time. What you might do is use the suggestion of @Jarod42 and make each `Manager` class a singleton so there can only be one of each. However I don't think it is worth the complexity.

Comment: I wouldn't bother. Even if you manage to achieve this, it'll be extremely complicated and hard to use. No way is it worthwhile. Just throw an exception when the lookup fails, like everybody else.

Comment: @Jarod42 I would be ok with that if I could somehow get the compiler to generate distinct types at compile time instead of manually entering 42, 43, or whatever. If not automatically generated types, then at the very least somehow introduce enough ambiguity to the type that the compiler cannot verify that they are compatible.  This would probably require some kind of dependent types trickery or something.

Comment: `I would be ok with that if I could somehow get the compiler to generate distinct types at compile time` Something like this perhaps: `Manager<Foo, class M1_tag> m1; Manager<Foo, class M2_tag> m2;` (you don't need to define `M1_tag` and `M2_tag` - elaborate class specifier serves as a declaration).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Huh, I didn't know that, cool, but I don't see much gained between needing to type `class M1_tag` instead of `42`.  I believe I would still need to manually ensure that the types are distinct one way or another.  Now, if I could do something like `<Foo, class>` (obviously wrong) that would generate a distinct, anonymous type for every usage of `<Foo, class>`, that would be cool and close to the ideal solution, I think.

Comment: It's much easier to come up with unique class names than with unique numbers. A particular instance of a `Manager<Foo, X>` probably plays a specific role in your program: name `X` after that role.